# Cannot Find The Page After Successful Hosting Of Service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have console application as host and wcf library project. When I want to host the application to `http://localhost:59350/GettingStarted/CalculatorService` it says that the page cannot be found. This code is from the msdn tutorials from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730935.aspx .

**Here is the code:**

```
using GettingStartedLib;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GettingStartedHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:59350/GettingStarted");

            ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), baseAddress);

            try
            {
                selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), new WSHttpBinding(), "CalculatorService");

                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;

                selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                selfHost.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
                Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate the service.");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();

                selfHost.Close();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException ce)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An exception occured: {0}", ce.Message);
                selfHost.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ICalculator**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace GettingStartedLib
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
    public interface ICalculator
    {
        [OperationContract]
        double Add(double n1, double n2);

        [OperationContract]
        double Subtract(double n1, double n2);

        [OperationContract]
        double Multiply(double n1, double n2);

        [OperationContract]
        double Devide(double n1, double n2);
    }
}
```

**CalculatorService**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace GettingStartedLib
{
    public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
    {
        public double Add(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 + n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Recieved Add {0},{1}", n1, n2);
            Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);

            return result;
        }

        public double Subtract(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 - n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Recieved Subtract {0},{1}", n1, n2);
            Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);

            return result;
        }

        public double Multiply(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 * n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Recieved Multiply {0},{1}", n1, n2);
            Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);

            return result;
        }

        public double Devide(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 / n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Recieved Devide {0},{1}", n1, n2);
            Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: every thing is ok, what is your problem certainly?

Comment: When i go to http://localhost:59350/GettingStarted/CalculatorService it is blank page ?

Comment: what you get in console using firebug

Comment: I've build your example and can access  localhost:59350/GettingStarted/CalculatorService without any problem. The msdn tutorial you refer to, has a note about configuring HTTP permissions. Have you done that?

Answer (score 0):

You can not access to your service with browser ,because you use self hosting.(it's different with web service)

you can use wcftestclient for testing wcf service, [Read this article](http://www.csharptutorial.in/35/how-to-test-wcf-service-using-wcf-test-client-in-vs-2010)

or you can add service refrence in VS for using service.